# Take backup and then drop all tables with same prefix in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In one of my Windows form application in asp .net, I am creating tables on daily basis sharp at 00:00 am with name as "data_YYYY_MM_DD" in Oracle database. A large amount of data exist in each table as after every 5 seconds I am writing some useful data into these.

Now consider all tables of month Oct 2016. All will have name like 'data_2016_10%'. How can I take backup of only these tables (not backup of entire database) and then drop these tables from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can take logical backup of these tables using data pump. It creates dump file(binary file) which can be imported as per your needs.

> #### Export:Table Mode
>
> A table mode export is specified using the TABLES parameter. In table mode, only a specified set of tables, partitions, and their dependent objects are unloaded.

**Example:**

```
expdp hr TABLES=hr.employees VERSION=LATEST DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=emp.dmp NOLOGFILE=YES
```

**Reference:**

[Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,
 you can schedule it in dbms_scheduler jobs,So that every day it will run and create backup table and drop existing table.Also please add exceptions like table does not exist...if you want

```
create or replace procedure backup_monthly_table
as 
prev_date varchar2(20) := to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
begin
for i in (select table_name from dba_tables where upper(table_name) like '%'||'"'||prev_date||'_%')
loop
dbms_output.put_line('working');
dbms_output.put_line(i.table_name);
execute immediate 'create table sysman.'||'"'||i.table_name||'_bkp'||'"'||' as select * from sysman.'||'"'||i.table_name||'"';
execute immediate 'drop table sysman.'||'"'||i.table_name||'"';
end loop;
end;

    verification  output:
select owner,table_name from dba_tables where upper (table_name) like '%2017-%'
    SYSMAN  2017-02-01_test1_bkp
    SYSMAN  2017-02-01_test2_bkp
    SYSMAN  2017-02-01_test3_bkp
SYSMAN  2017-02-01_test4_bkp
```